# 重複行を削除しつつ、最も古い日付のデータを抽出する方法

Tags: sql

製造商品に関わる２つのテーブルがあります

transaction as A

```
productID, GroupID, Date
3333,12,2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

product as B

```
productID, title
4444,namae
```

期待する結果

```
productID, Date, title
4444,2020-01-01 00:00:00, namae
```

この時、transactionのテーブルには販売された全レコードが入っているので、
全てを取得するのではなく、それぞれのproductIDの最も古いDateのデータだけが欲しいです。
(1行にproductIDはユニークの一つだけにしたい）

現状作成したコードは以下なのですが、これだと上記の通り全レコードが入ってしまうので、困っております。
お知恵をかしてください

```
SELECT A.Date, A.productID, B.title

From transaction as A
JOIN
product as B
ON A.productID = B.productID

WHERE
A.GroupID = 12
AND
A.Date between '2020-01-01 00:00:00 and '2020-01-31 23:59:59'
AND
(
B.title like 'hoge'
or
B.title like 'uma'
or
B.title like 'soba'
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where句の副問い合わせで最も古いデータに絞る方法はいかがでしょうか。
(Oracleで動作を確認し、予約語DateはDatに書き換えています)

SQL:

```
-- テーブル定義用
with transaction as
     (select 3333 productID, 12 GroupID, to_date('2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') Dat from dual union all
      select 4444 productID, 12 GroupID, to_date('2020-01-02 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') Dat from dual union all
      select 4444 productID, 12 GroupID, to_date('2020-01-03 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') Dat from dual union all
      select 5555 productID, 12 GroupID, to_date('2020-01-04 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') Dat from dual
     )
    ,product as
     (select 3333 productID, 'uma' title from dual union all
      select 4444 productID, 'namae' title from dual union all
      select 5555 productID, 'soba' title from dual
     )
-- コードここから
select A.Dat, A.productID, B.title
from  transaction A
     ,product B
where A.productID = B.productID
and   B.title like '%ma%'
-- 最も古いデータに絞る
and   A.Dat = (select min(tmp.Dat) from transaction tmp where tmp.productID = A.productID)
```

出力:

```
DAT,PRODUCTID,TITLE
2020/01/01,3333,uma
2020/01/02,4444,namae
```

Comment: 返答が遅れまして申し訳ございませんでした。誠にありがとうございます。